# Saving a PySpark dataframe to a parquet file raises Py4JJavaError

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, save, parquet

I am getting an exception when I try to save a `PySpark` dataframe.

Here is my code with a toy example:

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
sc = SparkContext('local')
spark = SparkSession(sc)
import pyspark
import pandas as pd

toy_df = '{"userId":{"0":1,"1":1,"10":1,"100":3,"1000":15,"10000":71,"10001":71,"10002":71,"10003":71,"10004":71},"movieId":{"0":31,"1":1029,"10":1371,"100":296,"1000":157,"10000":581,"10001":589,"10002":908,"10003":1171,"10004":1259},"rating":{"0":2.5,"1":3.0,"10":2.5,"100":4.5,"1000":2.0,"10000":4.0,"10001":3.0,"10002":5.0,"10003":5.0,"10004":4.0},"timestamp":{"0":1260748800000,"1":1260748800000,"10":1260748800000,"100":1298851200000,"1000":1052870400000,"10000":974592000000,"10001":974592000000,"10002":974592000000,"10003":974592000000,"10004":974592000000}}'
toy_df = pd.read_json(toy_df)

# Make the pandas dataframe a pyspark dataframe
toy = spark.createDataFrame(toy_df)

# Write the pyspark dataframe to disk
toy.write.save('toy', format='parquet', mode='append')
```

Error:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o152.save.

Comment: this is usually a package compilation mismatch (hadoop and spark). Try updating the versions/see if the versions support each other, if that doesnt work, please add info of the packages versions

Comment: @NotSoShabby:  I got the same error when trying to save the dataframe as a csv file.  Anyways, how can I do what you suggest?  Could you provide snippets of code that I will run from my Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: you need to update the packages versions. this is not done in jupyter notebook but where your python is located. are you using a virtual environment or running python straight on your computer?

Comment: I run Windows10 and run python straight on my computer. I have installed Python through Anaconda3.

Comment: run 'conda update pyspark' and try - open a new python notebook/rerun your python

Comment: I did as you said.  Conda reported that there was not pyspark installed and I run conda install pyspark.  After the installation completed I run again on the same error.  Moreoever, while when I run 'toy.columns' the columns are printed, when I run 'toy.show()' I am getting an exception (Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o42.showString.)

Comment: sounds like you didnt update the python that your using in your jupyter notebook. If you didnt have the package in the first place you would not get this error, you would get a 'no module named pyspak' because you didnt get this, im guessing you are running in a different environment than your own windows10 environment. run >>> import os
>>> import sys
>>> os.path.dirname(sys.executable)     in your notebook and run it in the command line python, and my guess is that they will point to different locations - thus meaning different environments

Comment: I run the command on Jupyter Notebook and I got: 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3'.  However I can not run a python command from the windows command prompt.  The system does not recognize the command py.  Any ways, what you suggest that I do?

Comment: there is no "anyways", these things are related and effect the solution.in your command line you need to run "python" first

Comment: I am sorry, I did not meant it in any disagreeable way.  Anyways, I did what you told me, run python in the command prompt entered the commands and I got the same answer as before: 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3'

Comment: maybe we will try this: in your jupyter notebook 'import pip' then run 'pip.main(['install', '--upgrade', 'pyspark'])'

Comment: I did as you told me:  AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute 'main'

Comment: run pip.__version__ to see which version of pip you have

Comment: I did that : '18.1'

Comment: create a chatroom and share with me, this is getting long. https://chat.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186624/discussion-between-user8270077-and-notsoshabby).